# REST API design - Withdraw Balance action

Tags: http, rest, restful-architecture

Currently designing a REST API and unsure how best to tackle a withdrawal action, for the purpose of the post ignore security as this is already handled.

Currently the **User** resource has a **balance** connection,

```
GET https://api.example.com/user/1/balance

{"balance":10}
```

would return the users **balance**.

Theres 2 ways I can think of to withdraw from this balance, either a *DELETE* on the **balance** connection or a new connection **withdraw** and then *POST* to this connection the amount.

*DELETE* implementation - Withdraw 5 points

```
DELETE https://api.example.com/user/1/balance?amount=5

{"balance":5}
```

*POST* implementation - Withdraw 5 points

```
POST https://api.example.com/user/1/withdraw
HTTP BODY: amount=5

{"balance":5}
```

Suggestions?

Personally I would go for the *POST* on the **withdraw** connection as this separates the action from the data, **withdraw** transactions could then be got with *GET* and cancelled with *DELETE*.

### Update

Another method could be to create a **transactions** connection on the **balance** object, then *POST* to this.

```
POST https://api.example.com/user/1/balance/transactions
HTTP BODY: amount=-5

{"balance":5}
```

Would this be a better a method? This would then create **transaction** resources on the **balance** resource.

Answer (score 5):

The DELETE option is not good choice because, according to the http semantics, you don't expect that consecutive DELETE requests of a resource can be accepted, I mean you expect that a resource can be deleted only one time.

Take into account that the withdrawal operation is non idempotent, it means that multiple request to the same resource can return different responses, because the request can change the status of the resource (balance amount).

For this type of non idempotent operations, is usual the use a POST method, something like this:

```
Request:

POST https://api.example.com/user/1/balance/transactions
HTTP BODY: {type:withdraw, amount:5}

Response:

200 OK {"balance":"5"}
401 Unauthorized {"message":"insufficient funds"}
```

Take a look to this resource that can be helpful.

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html